# jQuery plugin Chosen (enhances mutliselects) works great in Chrome, but slow in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, performance, multi-select, jquery-chosen, large-data

I'm currently using the [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
Check out my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3XWSe/

Try the fiddle in both Chrome and Internet Explorer (I tested using IE version 11).

Notice there is a delay (4 or 5 seconds) when clicking on the multiselect in Internet Explorer, as compared to very little, almost none, in Chrome. This example dropdown is listing all the cities in Texas and has close to 5000 options.

I opened up *chosen.jquery.js* and traced the problem to this call:

```
Chosen.prototype.update_results_content = function(content) {
    return this.search_results.html(content);  //<-- Problem here when loading the large amount of HTML into the element
};
```

I noticed that after the first click, if I stop `this.search_results.html` from updating on all subsequent clicks, the multiselect will no longer respond slowly. To fix the problem for the first click I would need to perhaps preload the content somehow. Any ideas?

**Any suggestions on how to fix this performance issue for IE**, or do you know of another **comparable jQuery plugin** that can handle these large amounts of options in IE? (I've tried *select2* and some others to no avail).

**EDIT:** Since this question has become popular over the year, I want to let everyone know that I abandoned Chosen and now use Select2 4.0 (which has excellent [performance with large data and infinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637588/how-to-use-local-json-and-infinite-scroll-together-in-select2-4-0)). It seems built to allow developers to decorate and alter it more easily and works on mobile.

Comment: I know my answer isn't what you wanted to hear... but its the truth unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question has become popular over the year, I want to let everyone know that I abandoned Chosen and now use **Select2 4.0**.

1. It's seems to be the most widely accepted successor of Chosen.
2. The 4.0 version [has excellent performance with large data and infinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637588/how-to-use-local-json-and-infinite-scroll-together-in-select2-4-0).
3. It seems built to allow developers to decorate and alter it more easily.
4. It works on mobile (unlike *Selectize*).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is something inherently wrong here. That being, **IE** sucks.

Even with **Chrome**, the rendering on my engine takes about **840ms**. For **IE**, we're talking about **3276ms**. This is due mainly to the way that **IE** renders the **DOM**. **Firefox** renders in **82ms**.

*This figure indicates IE 10, but even IE 11 has significant DOM related problems*
[image]

**Cited:** http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/chrome-27-firefox-21-opera-next,3534-6.html

Unfortunately, there is no problem with your code... there is a problem with your **browser.**

Comment: Yeah this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this deeper, the underlying issue is the `rnoInnerhtml` RegEx used to look for Script tags in the `jQuery.html()` functionality.  The RegEx used there is very slow in IE when rolling over large data sets.

```
/<(?:script|style|link)/i
```

A performance tweak to this RegEx may help the problem.

I also tweaked the Chosen Scripts and CSS to reduce the total size of the emitted html, which trims down the amount of data.

Comment: Ok...let me see if I can work this and get a solution. Then I can come back and accept the answer. Or if you had time, post an alternate regex to replace this one that fixes the IE speed issue. I think a lot of folks would appreciate it. No worries though, thanks for the insight! +1!!