# Strange behavior in dropdown search, when using jquery plugin Chosen for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, dropdownbox

Consider my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DFhAj/2/
I'm using the [popular jquery plugin Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

I have a `select` dropdown that looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Store North - New York, NY</option>
    <option>Store South - San Antonio, TX</option>
    <option>Store South #2 - San Antonio, TX</option>
    <option>Store East - Miami, FL</option>
</select>
```

When I click the dropdown and search for "store south", the 2 results correctly show. However, when I search for "san antonio", I get no results? It seems any search string that contains a **space** and appears after a **dash** doesn't work.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I'm judging you because of your HTML. Just thought you should know that.

Comment: It was mostly a joke, but legacy xHTML requires all lowercase. Also it makes the DOM view more consistent.

Comment: Gotcha...not sure why I uppercased here actually, most of my tags are consistently lowercase. Fixed.

Comment: Strange behaviour of chosen select. I faced that too. Didn't get any reasonable explanation. Here is the issue https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/573

Comment: My standard suggestion for Chosen issues is to upgrade to Select2, which is better supported. Syntax is virtually identical. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @isherwood, have you tried running `Select2` with a dropdown of 4000 options? `Chosen` performed MUCH better. I would write my own based on the jquery UI autocomplete/combobox if I had the time.

Comment: I haven't. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah it's much faster, but IE still has some performance issues: ['see my other stackoverflow question here'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322894/jquery-plugin-chosen-enhances-mutliselects-works-great-in-chrome-but-slow-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `search_contains: true`:

```
$('select').chosen({
    search_contains: true
});
```

You can read more on the docs [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html).

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFhAj/3/)**

Comment: Awww...that options page eluded me. It's mentioned only at the bottom FAQ. I was about to dive into the code more. Thank you!